# How to raise exception for non-existent class member?

Tags: python, class

I have a method for automatically creating Python classes that wrap database tables, with class members that have the same name as the fields in the table.  The class files look like this:

```
class CpsaUpldBuildChrgResultSet(Recordset):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super().__init__(connection)
        self.DefaultTableName = 'cpsa_upld_build_chrg_result'
        self._keyFields.append('j_trans_seq')
        self._keyFields.append('j_index')

    @property
    def j_trans_seq(self):
        return self.GetValue('j_trans_seq')
    @j_trans_seq.setter
    def j_trans_seq(self, value):
        self.SetKeyValue('j_trans_seq', value)

    @property
    def j_index(self):
        return self.GetValue('j_index')
    @j_index.setter
    def j_index(self, value):
        self.SetKeyValue('j_index', value)
```

I just found that if I try to set a value for a non-existent class member, such as J_TRANS_SEQ, no exception is thrown.  Is there something I can add to this class so that an attempt to access a non-existent member would raise an exception?

Comment: Hi, maybe you could raise you own exception. `if...: raise...` or `assert`? What do you think?

Answer (score 6):

You can add a `__setattr__` method to your class that raises an `AttributeError` whenever an invalid attribute is assigned to. I'm not sure exactly how you'd want to determine which attributes are valid and which are not, but one approach might be something like this:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if hasattr(self, name):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
    else:
        raise AttributeError("{} object has no attribute {!r}".format(type(self), name))
```

This assumes that any attribute that can be looked up is also valid to be assigned to. It might break if your `property`'s getters don't work unless the setter is called before the getter. It might also be too permissive, since it would allow setting of instance attributes that override class attributes (such as `__init__`). Another approach might be to check the name against a white-list of known attributes (but be sure to include the attributes that you need for the inherited class machinery, like `DefaultTableName` and `_keyFields`).

Comment: On Python 3.10 at least, this fails with `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'setattr'`. It seems to work with `super().__setattr__(name, value)` instead.

Comment: Oh hell, that's not a version specific thing. That's just a silly five year old typo. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Blckknght has the right idea, but left out some important details in his answer—such has how class attributes (class members) are set the first time, when they don't preexist, such as in the typical scenario when the class's `__init__()` method executes. Here's a more fully fleshed-out answer that works in Python 3 which addresses that deficiency.

It also shows how to minimize the coding of a bunch of repetitive properties.

```
class Recordset(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        print('Recordset.__init__({!r}) called'.format(connection))

    def SetKeyValue(self, name, value):
        print('SetKeyValue({!r}, {!r}) called'.format(name, value))

    def GetValue(self, name):
        print('GetValue({!r}) called'.format(name))

def fieldname_property(name):
    storage_name = '_' + name

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self.GetValue(storage_name)
    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        self.SetKeyValue(storage_name, value)

    return prop

class CpsaUpldBuildChrgResultSet(Recordset):
    # define properties for valid fieldnames
    j_trans_seq = fieldname_property('j_trans_seq')
    j_index = fieldname_property('j_index')

    def __init__(self, connection):
        super().__init__(connection)
        self._setter('DefaultTableName', 'cpsa_upld_build_chrg_result')

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            self._setter(name, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No field named %r" % name)

    def _setter(self, name, value):
        """Provides way to intentionally bypass overloaded __setattr__."""
        super().__setattr__(name, value)


print('start')
db_table = CpsaUpldBuildChrgResultSet('SomeConnection')
print('assigning attributes...')
db_table.j_trans_seq = 42  # OK
db_table.j_index = 13  # OK
db_table.J_TRANS_SEQ = 99  # -> AttributeError: No field named 'J_TRANS_SEQ'
print('done')
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to show this to me!

Comment: I'm not sure I can use this answer, now that I'm looking more closely.  In my original post, note that j_trans_seq's setter calls a method in the class's base class.  In the solution above, the setter calls __setattr__() instead.  How do I call GetKeyValue() instead?

Comment: You should be able to call `self.SetKeyValue()` in the property setter. The principle point of my answer was simply to illustrate how to bypass the overloaded `__setattr__()`. Without some way of doing that, it would be impossible to initially create attributes—something often needing to be done, for example, in a class's `__init__()` method when class instances are created...and something not addressed in @Blckknght's answer.

Comment: I figured as much.  But when I tried it, I ran into another problem:  when setting an attribute of my parent class, I got the AttributeError.  Does hasattr() look at parent classes?  I think it probably does.  I think the problem is that I'm not calling my parent class's __init__() when I should.  I need to understand Python's object construction and initialization a lot better than I do.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, it looks at parent classes. See if my recent update helps. It's more like the code in your question rather than just an abstraction.